# Can I give DC 12V to a AC 12V input?

Tags: power-supply, ac, dc

I have a circuit that takes 12V AC as an input but my bench power supply only delivers 12V DC, is there any issue if I give the device DC instead of AC? (Same voltage)

Straight after the input there is a 4 diodes bridge to make it DC so I would say that it's not a problem since the current would flow only through 2 diodes instead of 4, just want to be sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a bridge rectifier and want to feed 12VDC into it, there are a few things to consider.

In 12VAC, peak voltage would be about 17V, so whatever is after the rectifier (say a linear regulator possibly) its expecting 17V (minus diodes drop). If it is for example, a typical 7812 12V regulator, it needs at least 14V to work properly. If its a lower voltage regulator (say, unlikely 9V or 5V) it might work fine.

With AC, current flows through 4 diodes, feeding DC only uses 2. So they have to handle double the current (which may or may not be fine).

I wouldnt really recommend doing it this way. If it has a rectifier it probably uses DC somewhere down the line, and if you have a bench supply you can feed it there.

p.s.: you might want to take the precaution of disconnecting unused parts of the circuit, some regulators dont like to have voltage on their output higher than input and your circuit might not have protection for this.

p.p.s.: clarified in the comments but written here for future reference: a full bridge rectifier can give positive and negative power rails, which 12VDC do not supply.

Comment: The only thing I have after the bridge are resistors and capacitors, no 7812 regulator. The circuit board is an amplifier. And right after the bridge I have a capacitor of 3300µF any recommandation knowing that?

Comment: do you know how much current it consumes? is it a preamp, power amp, headphone "amp"? can you upload a picture of it?

Comment: It's a power amp, it's more or less the same as this one http://www.goodluckbuy.com/2-1ch-tda2030a-amp-pcb-board-components-kit-for-diy-power-amplifier-.html

Comment: hmm most likely it will not work. It needs both a positive and a negative rail. There are single supply configurations but I don't believe this is the case. Also you would have considerably less output power due to limited supply range (probably somewhere close to 2W looking at the ICs datasheet).

Comment: If you really want to use this board I would salvage a transformer from old linear PSU bricks. If you really need to use 12VDC I would recommend a Class-D (or Class-T) amp.

Comment: Great thanks Wesley. I still have the 230-12V AC power supply, just wanted to make the prototyping easier by using my bench instead of a non isolated transformer lying on the desk :)

Answer (score 1):

Linear regulators like 7812 needs 2v or more above the output voltage as input in order for them to work properly. Example, you want a regulated 12v dc output, you have to at least give an input of 14v. This is not the only allowance you have to take consideration. The input goes to the bridge rectifier first then to the regulator. The bridge also drops 1v or so of voltage. So you need to account for that. To be safe, if you want a regulated 12v dc output, you must at least supply 14v dc input (no bridge) since it is already dc, or 12v ac or above as input. Why is 12v ac ok as input to produce regulated 12v dc? As WL has answered, 12v ac has a peak of 17v. But if I were to make a regulated 12v dc, I will not use 12v ac input. I'll use 13vac or 14vac just to be sure. But not 15vac as there will be so much excess energy to dissipate.